# execCommand bold don't toggle in firefox

Tags: javascript, execcommand

in FireFox, I can set the selection bold, but when I click one time more, the selected bold text dont unbolding...

How to fix this?

Normal (Dont work):

```
document.execCommand("bold", false, null); 
/
document.execCommand("bold", false, "");
```

My Try (dont work also):

```
if (document.queryCommandState("bold")) {
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, ""+ document.getSelection()+"");
    } else {
    
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<b>"+ document.getSelection()+"</b>");
        
    }
```

Comment: So you want selected text to be bold, right? Why not use pure CSS?

Comment: how do you mean this? i have a h1 Content= editable, maybe this can help you rather. @LudovitMydla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tested and Passed on Chrome and Firefox

`execComand('bold'...` [**Toggles** the style on and off of a selected part of text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands).

So to trigger toggling, use `execCommand()` in a callback function of an **Event Handler** that is registered for a *"toggling"* type of event such as: `click`,`dblclick`,`mousedown/up`, etc..

The `execCommand()` is a versatile yet specialized **Document Extension** in that most commands (*methods?*) rely on selected text, clicking events, keystrokes, etc. Basically, `execCommand()` is a text editor so when utilizing it, keep in mind the interface has a strong association to aspects involving text formatting and editing.

The following Demo has:

1. An [**onclick Event Attribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) that toggles **"bold"** command.
2. An [**EventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) registered to the "double-click (`dblclick`)" event. It toggles the *"italic"* command.
3. An [**onmousedown Property Event Handler**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) which toggles the "underline" command.

---

### Demo

```js
// double-click EventListener 
document.getElementById('I').addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
  document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
});

// mousedown Property Event Handler
document.getElementById('U').onmousedown = function(e) {
  document.execCommand('underline', false, null);
};
```

```css
#editor1 {
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px inset grey
}
```

```html
<div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">
  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
</div>

<fieldset>

  <button id='I' class="fontStyle" title="Italicize Highlighted Text"><i>I</i>
    </button>

  <!-- click on Event Attribute -->
  <button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'bold',false,null);" title="Bold Highlighted Text"><b>B</b>
    </button>

  <button id="U" class="fontStyle" title="Underline Highlighted Text"><u>U</u>
    </button>

</fieldset>
```